# Can I manually override Amazon Cognito's Lockout?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I'm trying to work through reconfirming a user who did not complete Cognito's verification code step, but I am hindered by an error reading "Attempt limit exceeded, please try after some time." I have tried deleting and recreating the user from the user pool, but the same error appears on the next test run.

Is there a way to override the attempt limit, either through the AWS console or some other means? The lockout period is an annoying barrier for testing, and I wonder if there is anything I could do if this scenario came up with a real-life user.